# ArrayList in Graphiew

Tags: android, arraylist, android-graphview

I have two double `ArrayList` (ArrayList) how can I pass these arrayLists to `GraphView` to draw my linear chart?
for limited points we can use these codes :

```
GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new   DataPoint[] {
      new DataPoint(0, 1),
      new DataPoint(1, 5),
      new DataPoint(2, 3),
      new DataPoint(3, 2),
      new DataPoint(4, 6)
});
```

but my ArrayLists have thousands points!

Comment: could you show your ArrayList?

Comment: for example:   ArrayList<Integer> X=[1, 4, 5, 5, 8 ,8 ,......] and   ArrayList<Integer> Y=[10, 45, 57, 54, 18, 81 ,......]

Answer (score 0):

You can do like,

```
LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new   DataPoint[] {
  new DataPoint(X[0], Y[0]),
  new DataPoint(X[1], Y[1]),
  new DataPoint(X[2], Y[2]),
  new DataPoint(X[3], Y[3]),
  new DataPoint(X[4], Y[4])
});
```

OR

```
If u have bulk of data means use `for loop`
```

this may helps you.

Comment: thanks for replay, but my arraylists have thousands and thousands points how can I use your code? using a "for" loop?

Comment: yeah yo can use for loop

Comment: it doesn't work...when I put for loop in the LineGraphSeries, I've got an error. the error is ";" expected... but everything is OK and the ";" has been entered

Answer (score 0):

If you want to populate the `LineGraphSeries` with 1000 point then you should consider to define a list and pass this when you construct the object of the
`LineGraphSeries` class

## Example

```
List<DataPoint> myPointList = ....
LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(Arrays.asList(myPointList));
....
```