# How can I create array of data type linegraphseries of multiple members?

Tags: android, android-graphview

How can I create array of data type linegraphseries of ten members.
Some thing like:

```
LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series1 = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[] {});
```

to:

```
LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>[] series1 = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[] {})[10];
```

But this code not working.

Comment: add only 10 data first and then click more button then load another data.

Comment: I do not want 10 data points. I want to create Linegraphseries array.

Comment: I hope it'll help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38282369

Comment: Link shows how to use data point array. But not LineGraphSeries Array. I just want to create multiple series with same name but with array so that one single name have multiple series

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you [cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559092) create an array for a parameterized type, but you can create an `ArrayList` of `LineGraphSeries` like this:

```
ArrayList<LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>> series = new ArrayList<>(3);
```